# Getting List of default argument values if not used in FFMPEG command execution

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

When I use FFMPEG to capture a live IPTV stream on my MAC, I generally end up with an interrupted video. When I send these four arguments, the capture is successful.

-reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2

I don't want to specify these arguments everytime, So I decided to update the default values in the source code. Unsure if I have done it right - I updated http.c which contains these arguments. I re-compiled FFMPEG successfully.

I want to know if my changes are applied. Is there a way I can list out all the default values of the arguments. I can use this compiled version of FFMPEG for a week, and determine if the fix is applied or not, I was wondering, if there is a quicker and easier way to do it.

If this is successful, I can use this version of FFMPEG for Emby & TellyTV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ffmpeg -h protocol=http`

This will print all options, and mention default value in the description

e.g.

```
 -reconnect_at_eof  <boolean>    .D........ auto reconnect at EOF (default false)
```

Comment: Yes, I can see the default applied argument values. Thank you!!